# Less CSS Import Problem

Tags: css, less

Im dealing here with Less CSS. Everythings was going fine, but im getting a little bug now.
I have two less files. The first is called "colors.less" where i declared the colors vars, and the second is the css structure.

Its something like this:

**color.less**

```
@black: #000;
```

**styles.less**

```
@import "color";

body {
    background: @black;
}
```

In my head tag, im writing it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/styles.less"/>
```

And of course, importing the less js.

Whats happening is when i change the black color to White (#fff), it dont change to white. Stills black. When i reverse the logic, import the styles inside of color, it changes, but my styles dont change.

What im doing wrong?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
@import "color.less";
```

This probely solve you problem. If this don´t fix the issue try use a red color in you color.less cause if the you browser default color is black you will not see if the style ins´t loaded.

PS: Check your file names like color.less or colorS.less.

Comment: Should have a semi-colon on the end but I'm just being picky.

Comment: You can also

`@import "color.css";`

Answer (score 2):

LESS uses css syntax so you need the file extension:

```
@import "color.less";
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

Could you have the `color` within the main `stylesheet` and not reference the second `sheet`?

Then you could skip the `@import`.

Also, I would pick another name for the style `rule`.  If you decide to change the color, your rule name will not make sense.

Comment: Im using LESS because i need my style dynamic. The user will set the colors on admin, and these colors will be saved on the color.less file. About the rule name, i tried it, i've put another name and didnt work too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what could be causing this, but try referencing both files in yout `<head>`-tag like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/styles.less"/>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/color.less"/>
```

And then also change your `style.less` to not import `color.less` since you're doing that in your `<head>`-tag already.

Btw: I wouldn't call the color  `@black`, this may lead to confusion when changing the color later on, try to use more descriptive names like `@mainBackgoundColor` instead, to get code that reads well too.

Comment: @Lucas :
another idea: try using `@import "./color.less";` (or `"./color"` if you prefer it), i just used this to import sth a minute ago and it worked flawlessly

also, when you update one of the imported files, update the importing one as well (just add a space somewhere or sth), i think less may be doing some caching or sth under the hood.

Answer (score -6):

Whatever file you are importing has to have a .css extension. Only the containing, or retrieving, file can have the .less extension.

In your example, the color file should have a .css extension instead of .less. This should fix you right up.

**Update
Worked in Chrome, not in Firefox
?? Weird.